# Visual Basic & Context Menu

Tags: vb.net, winforms, popupmenu

Is there a way to add a Header to the popup menu? I don't find a property for this.

Comment: Let me ask you this: have you ever seen a popup menu with a header?  One that wasn't just a normal command item that didn't do anything, that is.

Comment: coming to think of it you are right. But my situation is that this popup will be off a datagridview and it is row sensitive and since the user can pop up this menu on a non current row they might get confused at times that the item they are selecting is not the one that is highlighted. So I thought puting the item they are clicking on as the header or something like that. Do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also simulate a header on the context menu by putting the information you want to display in the header as the first item in the context menu.  Put a separator (or perhaps two) underneath it and put no code behind it.

That visually separates the item and users will learn pretty quick that clicking the first item doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work in your situation, but whenever I needed to show a context menu off of a grid row that wasn't the current/highlighted row, I made that row the current row first, then showed the menu.  That would eliminate the need for a header on the menu.  I assume you're showing the context menu if the user right clicks on the row.  Well before showing the context menu, make sure that row is current and highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Corin says, but disable the first item as well. If you disable it, that should remove confusion entirely.